# Akka Reactive Streams purpose of the Processor

Tags: stream, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I'm trying to undestand Reactive Streams in akka. I've read this blog http://bryangilbert.com/blog/2015/02/04/akka-reactive-streams/ and I think I get the basic idea of how it works. What I don't understand however, is the purpose of the Processer within this concept. What is it for? 
Isn't it enough for the Subscriber to request N-Objects and the Publisher to send them using onNext()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a real simple process flow, just a Source (publisher) and a Sink (subscriber). You hook these two up and the sink subscribes into the publisher and starts requesting data and the data flows to the sink. In this example all you really need is a publisher and subscriber.  But in this example, nothing happens to the data along the way from source to sink. It's not transformed in any way and is therefore not very interesting and not very useful.

A Processor combines both the Publisher and Subscriber interfaces and can therefore act as both of those roles. A processor is meant to be snapped in to a processing flow between the source and sink and transform the data. If I fit one into the source/sink example from before, the flow of data and who is subscribing to what changes. Now the sink subscribes into that processor and the processor in turn subscribes into the source. The sink requests elements from the processor and the processor propagates that demand upstream to the source. It is also responsible for pushing elements downstream to the sink when there are elements to meet demand. That's why it has to implement both interfaces as it has to fill both roles.

With each processing step you add, like a `map` or `filter`, you are adding another place where back pressure can be handled. These steps are not the initiation point (source) or the destination (sink) for the data. All they are meant to do is receive data and do something to it or alter the flow of it and send elements downstream to meet demand. Because they need to be able to link into any chain they need both publish and subscribe functionality and that's why Processor exists.

Comment: So basically all it does is stand in between, alter the data if necessary and puffer it some more?

Comment: @Rise, the Processor really enables everything about reactive streams.  Streams is all about manipulating and data and modifying flows and without the Processor to stand in there for those stages all you would have is a source -> sink flow and nothing in between.  By being this little self contained Pub/Sub pairing it allows you to tie into existing flows and make modifications and still handle backpressure and potentially even change the effect of backpressure (via something like `buffer`)

Comment: But the same thing without a Processor would still be reactive? The sink would still ask for the amount of data it can handle would it not?

Comment: @Rise, yes, it would still be reactive (albeit not very interesting of a flow)